# Standard ML: Datatype vs. Structure

Tags: structure, sml

I'm reading through Paulson's *ML For the Working Programmer* and am a bit confused about the distinction between datatypes and structures.

On p. 142, he defines a type for binary trees as follows:

```
datatype 'a tree = Lf
    | Br of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree;
```

This seems to be a recursive definition where 'a denotes some fixed type.  So any time I see 'a, it must refer to the same type throughout.

On p. 148, he discusses a structure for binary trees:

"...we have been following an imaginary ML session in which we typed in the tree functions one at a time.  Now we ought to collect the most important of those functions into a structure, called *Tree*.  We really must do so, because one of our functions (*size*) clashes with a built-in function.  One reason for using structures is to prevent such name clashes.

We shall, however, leave the datatype declaration of *tree* outside of the structure.  If it were inside, we should be forced to refer to the constructors by *Tree.Lf* and *Tree.Br*, which would make our patters unreadable.  Thus, in the sequel, imagine that we have made the following declarations:

```
datatype 'a tree = Lf
    | Br of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree;

structure Tree = 
    struct
    fun size Lf = 0
        | size (Br( v, t1, t2)) = 1 + size t1 + size t2;
    fun depth...
    etc...
    end;
```

I'm a little confused.

1) What is the relationship between a datatype and a structure?

2) What is the role of "struct" within the structure definition?

3) Later on, Paulson discusses a structure for dictionaries as binary search trees.  He does the following:

```
structure Dict : DICTIONARY = 
    struct

    type key = string;
    type 'a t = (key * 'a) tree;
    val empty = Lf;

    <a bunch of functions for dictionaries>
```

This makes me think struct specifies the different primitive or compound types involved int he definition of a Dict.

That's a really fuzzy definition though.  Anyone like to clarify?

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Answer (score 7):

A structure is a *module*. Everything between the `struct` and `end` keywords forms the body of this module. Similarly, you can view a signature as the description of an abstract module *interface*. Ascribing a signature to a structure (like the `: DICTIONARY` syntax does in your example) limits the *exports* of the module to what is specified in that signature (by default, everything would be accessible). That allows you to hide implementation details of a module.

However, ML modules are much richer than that. They can be arbitrarily nested. There are also *functors*, which are effectively functions from modules to modules ("parameterised modules", if you want). Altogether, the module language in ML forms a full functional language on its own, with structures as the basic entities, functors over them, and signatures describing the "types" of such modules. This little language is a layer on top of the so-called *core* language, where ordinary values and types live.

So, to answer your individual questions:

1) There is no specific relationship between the datatype and the structure. The latter simply uses the former.

2) `struct`-`end` is simply a keyword pair to delimit the structure body (languages in C tradition would probably use curly braces there).

3) As explained above, a structure is a basic module. It can contain (and export) arbitrary other language entities, including other modules. By grouping definitions together, and potentially hiding some of them through a signature ascription, you can express namespacing and encapsulation (in particular, abstract data types).

I should also note that Paulson's book is outdated regarding its description of modules, as it predates the current language version. In particular, it does not describe how to express abstract data types through modules, but instead introduces the obsolete `abstype` declaration which nobody has been using in almost 20 years. A more extensive and up-to-date introduction to modular programming in ML can be found in Harper's [Programming in Standard ML](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/smlbook/book.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

In this example, the datatype `'a tree` is describing a binary tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) that is capable of storing any value of a single type. The `'a` in the definition is a variant type which will later be constrained down to a concrete type wherever tree is used with a different type. This allows you to define the structure of a tree once and then use it with any type later on.

The Tree structure is separate from the datatype definition. It is being used to group functions together that operate on the `'a tree` datatype. It is being used right now as a way to modularize the code and, as it points out, to prevent namespace clashes.

`struct` is just an identifier keyword to let the compiler know where your structure definition starts while the `end` keyword is used to let the compiler know where the definition ends.

The dictionary structure is defining a dictionary (a key -> value data structure) that uses a tree as the internal data structure. Once again, the structure is a collection of functions that will be used to create and operate on dictionaries. The `type`s within the dictionary structure compose the type of the internal data structure that makes up the dictionary. The following functions define the public interface that you're exposing to allow clients to work with dictionaries.

Comment: So why is 'a tree not considered a structure?  I'm coming from an OOP background and it seems like "structure" should just be synonymous with class and that one class can have fields that are other classes.  So I'm a little lost on the datatype vs. structure distinction...it's not as if 'a tree is a primitive type or something...thanks again

Comment: In functional programming there's an inherent separation between the types and the code. Think of the types as a formal proof that the program is well formed. If the types don't line up, then the program clearly won't do what you want it to. The code is you telling the system how to manipulate data to have it line up with the types. In the case of a tree, you are defining a type that describes a recursive tree where each element has a value and two children or nothing. Structures are similar to classes, but also not the same because internal state isn't a thing.

Comment: Hmm, aren't structures holding state though?  All of the key, value pairs seem to be examples of internal state.  I guess I'm still not totally clear what datatype is doing...sorry to be a pain

Comment: Well, they're kind of holding state. A dictionary is controlled and created by the dictionary structure and has the type `'a t`. It doesn't have the type dictionary. Instead, you use the structure to modify the state. For example, I'm assuming the dictionary structure has something like a create function that returns an empty `'a t`. You can bind that to a variable then use other functions defined in the structure to immutably update it.